# How does the browser know if a script is finished loading?

Tags: javascript

How does the web browser know if the script inside `<script>` tag has finished loading?

Comment: I'm not sure of the answer to this, but one might assume that it depends on the browser.

Comment: Finishes loading or finishes executing?

Comment: Are you referring to an inline script or an external script? In any case, the browser is the program responsible for loading the page and any resources, so it always knows when anything gets loaded.

Comment: Please tell us the problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onload` event fires when a resource (such as a script, or stylesheet) is loaded:

```
var oScript = document.createElement("script");
oScript.type = "text\/javascript";
oScript.onload = function () {
  // do something when the script is loaded
}
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(oScript);
oScript.src = "path/to/script";
```

The `onload` event does not work on inline scripts.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to know when a specific script tag has finished parsing, trigger some custom event at the end of its code or immediately after it.